# error saving image on client side with multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

So basically I'm working with Express and multer, I have this piece of code:

```
export const uploadFile = async (req, res) => {
try {
    setTimeout(async () => {
        const user = req.user
        const findUser = await userController.getUserById(user._id)
        const baseUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host')+'/'
        const files = req.files
        const fileName = files.profileImage[0]

        const documents = []
        for (const file in files) {
            if (file !== 'profileImage' && file !== 'productImage') {
                const filesToUpload = files[file];
                filesToUpload.forEach(file => {
                    documents.push({
                        file: file.fieldname,
                        reference: file.path
                    });
                });
            }
        }
        const pathImg = fileName.destination
        findUser.img = `${baseUrl}${pathImg.replace('public/', '')}/${fileName.filename}`
        await userController.updateUser(user._id, findUser)
        res.redirect("/profile")
    }, 2000)


} catch (err) {
    logger.error(err)
}
```

}

basically what I am doing here is saving the image path in the img attribute of the user object, which would be: "http://localhost:4040/img/profiles/profileImage-Manumanu2.png".
This works fine in localhost, as when I try to render the image, I would use user.img to get the image path.
I used lightsail to host my project, and when I try to do the same, I get this error:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'public/img/profiles/profileImage-Manumanu2.png'
i
I suspect the issue is within  the baseUrl variable, maybe req.get('host') does not work in this case?